# Domínio com 'www' não funciona

Tags: apache, domínio

Eu fiz uma configuração do Apache na Digital Ocean, só que o domínio só funciona sem o `www`. Abaixo está a minha configuração:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@dominio.com
    ServerName dominio.com
    ServerAlias www.dominio.com *.dominio.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dominio
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_dominio.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_dominio.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado, ou se precisa de mais algum comando?

Comment: Já tentou verificar o `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Você mapeou a entrada do tipo A corretamente sem www para o seu ip? Eu tive esse problema e resolvi por lá.

Comment: Josivan de souza, está um @ com meu ip no tipo A

Comment: Deixa em branco e veja o resultado.

Comment: Conseguir resolver Josivan de souza, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Legal @VictorRajesh, posta a solução aplicada aqui para compartilhar com a comunidade. Saudações.

Comment: Criei um CNAME com o www, e o meu domínio

Comment: @VictorRajesh Se puder, crie para essa sua pergunta a resposta assim como fizeste no comentário. Dessa forma a pergunta ficará marcada como respondida.